# react native: there is way to position icon only in the 3 tab of the accordion from native-base lib?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons, native-base

there is way to put icon "eye" from the "react-native-vector-icons directory - MaterialIcons"
i need put the "eye" icon **only in the 3 position** of the accordion.
this accordion come from the "native-base" lib.

this is the example that i want to achieve  :

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion } from "native-base";
const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
];
export default class AccordionHeaderContentStyleExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={dataArray}
            headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#b7daf8" }}
            contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ddecf8" }}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

https://snack.expo.io/9dGIGdAsg

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Icon, Accordion, Text, View } from "native-base";
const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", icon: "visibilty" }
];

export default class AccordionCustomHeaderContent extends Component {
  _renderHeader(item, expanded) {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        padding: 10,
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center" ,
        backgroundColor: "#A9DAD6" }}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}>
          {" "}{item.title}
        </Text>
        {item.icon && (<Icon style={{ fontSize: 18 }} name="remove-circle" />)}
      </View>
    );
  }
  _renderContent(item) {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#e3f1f1",
          padding: 10,
          fontStyle: "italic",
        }}
      >
        {item.content}
      </Text>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={dataArray}
            animation={true}
            expanded={true}
            renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            renderContent={this._renderContent}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
<br/>
```

Comment: i did already , can u tell me how i put the icon only in the 3 tab of the accordion ? i didnt find way .

Comment: Do u have code somewhere I can access it? maybe expo? otherwise, I need setup everything for react-native

Comment: The app does not work on the expo. has some error with navigation instance

Answer (score 0):

you can customize header view with it's function "renderHeader" by passing view in it but if you want to add customize view on a particular index of header then you would have to customize it a little bit.

It's default param return following

```
renderHeader(item, expanded)
```

You would have to edited "src/basic/Accordion.js" class in library and change it like following

```
renderHeader(item, expanded, index)
```

Then you will get index of the header item of Accordin then you can customize it's view by condition like if index == 2 (item 3) then add "eye" icon

Comment: I prefer not to touch the library itself but thanks anyway.

Comment: It's not providing the index of item so if we need, we have to customize it a little bit. Thanks